# wordpress home page empty

Tags: wordpress, footer

The wordpress home page is empty, which claims to be the front page, and when I view the front page, which has a ton of content, and click edit page, it takes me to the word press page editor for home page, which is empty. Where can I locate the  files for this homepage! In particular need to change the footer around on the theme fresh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether any template assigned for your home page (you can do via `Page Attributes` section on sidebar) and if yes, check for the particular template in your theme directory.

If `Template` section says `Default Template`, then look at the 'front-page.php' in your theme folder.

If you want to edit the footer, it would be probably 'footer.php'.